# page loading long time due to join query inside for loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have created a function to display records in a page by using below code,but page take long time to load due to join query.Can anyone find issue and provide solution for this?

```
public function baleList($program_id) {
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from(GIN_PROCESS);
        $this->db->where('ginner_id', $this->prscr_id);
        $this->db->where('program', $program_id);
        $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result_array(); 
        $id_array = array_column($result, 'id');
        $bales_list = array(); 
        foreach ($id_array as $id) {
            $this->db->select('gp.id, gp.lot_no, SUM(gb.weight) AS weight, SUM(gb.staple) AS staple, SUM(gb.mic) AS mic, SUM(gb.strength) AS strength, SUM(gb.trash) AS trash, gb.color_grade');
            $this->db->from(GIN_BALES . ' gb');
            $this->db->join(GIN_PROCESS . ' gp', 'gp.id=gb.process_id');
            $this->db->where('gb.process_id', $id);
            $this->db->where('gb.sold_status', 0);
            $lot_details = $this->db->get()->result(); 

            if (count($lot_details) > 0) {
                $this->db->select('*');
                $this->db->from(GIN_BALES);
                $this->db->where('sold_status', 0);
                $this->db->where('process_id', $id);
                $bales = $this->db->get()->result();
                if (count($bales) > 0) {
                    $lot_details[0]->bales = $bales;
                    $bales_list[] = $lot_details[0];
                }
            }
        }
        return $bales_list;
    }
```

Is there any seperate function for this inner queries?

[ginprocess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqkAd.png)

[ginbale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhsLG.png)

Comment: Also most likely the query also results into giving invalid results as it is not allowed to mix aggregate columns (`SUM()`) with non-aggregated columns without using GROUP BY as the non-aggregated columns are nondeterministic (random).. See [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) it is mentioned there.

Comment: But this function runs and shows result.After database records count increased,this loading issue happens.

Comment: For More Info:
1. SELECT `id` FROM `gin_process` WHERE `ginner_id` = '74' AND `program` = '5' ORDER BY `id` DESC

2. SELECT `gp`.`id`, `gp`.`lot_no`, SUM(gb.weight) AS weight, SUM(gb.staple) AS staple, SUM(gb.mic) AS mic, SUM(gb.strength) AS strength, SUM(gb.trash) AS trash, `gb`.`color_grade` FROM `gin_bales` `gb` JOIN `gin_process` `gp` ON `gp`.`id`=`gb`.`process_id` WHERE `gb`.`process_id` = '1134' AND `gb`.`sold_status` =0

3. SELECT * FROM `gin_bales` WHERE `sold_status` =0 AND `process_id` = '1134'

Comment: it run yes if sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is disabled but it does not mean it runs with correct results as the results are most likely to be invalid as the SQL is invalid... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results.. Without we can't help you optimize this.. Also we need table structues for every table involved in the question (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table)`

Comment: I have added image for reference in above description

Comment: images are not good for Reproducible Examples which you are required to make as Stackoverflow guidelines [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section see *"Help others reproduce the problem"*

Comment: also we need to have expected results based on the example data the link ive has a tool to make ascii based data tables ...

Answer (score 0):

Well, executing a query n times sure is a performance killer. Try adding a "GROUP BY gb.process_id", remove the loop itself and use a "WHERE gb.process_id IN ($id_array)". You may need to use "ANY_VALUE()" within your select to select columns without min/max/etc.